# Is it possible to style AlertDialog independently of activity's theme?

Tags: android, user-interface, dialog, android-alertdialog

I realize the question is kind of weird, but I want to stop using deprecated options menu and switch to action bar. Unfortunately, to do that I must use Holo theme, which comes with a different AlertDialog design that was before.

This new design breaks my UI appearance. Is it possible to create an old-styled dialog in a Holo-styled activity?

Arelated question: is there any thing other than AlertDialog that is a pop-up window capable of showing my own layout, and that doesn't have borders and other theme-defined stuff around my custom layout?

Comment: which is your minimumSdkversion set in your manifest and which is targetSdkVersion?

Comment: @Android-Developer: min is 12, target used to be 10 for the menu to be available, now I'd like to set it to at least 14. Was 17 just now when I was testing.

Comment: you can use your custom layout as alertdialog

Comment: @AmitHooda: I did just that, but AlertDialog in Holo has a thick border I need to get rid of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the minSDKVersion set in your AndroidManifest file you can choose a theme for your dialog. You can set them to Holo / Device Default but to do that your minSdk value should be 10+ even I think that to use DeviceDefault it should be JellyBean.

If you want to create your own layout and use it without any borders and etc which will break your design you should use Dialog instead of AlertDialog and customize it. You can do something like this :

```
final Dialog alert = new Dialog(FingerPaintActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Light_Panel);
alert.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // no title 
alert.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.PauseDialogAnimation; // this is used for custom animation when dialog is showing and hiding 
alert.setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.stamps, null)); // here is your custom layout
alert.getWindow().setLayout(width-50, (height-100)); // set height / width
```

and when you want to trigger an onlclick in your button for example which is placed in R.layout.stamps as in the example you should do like this :

```
Button dog = (Button) alert.findViewById(R.id.dog_stamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `AlertDialog`.

For example : http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Comment: But I want the opposite, unless I'm missing something about that project